# render inputtext field on ajax call from selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2

when I change selection from h:selectOneMenu, it correctly renders the output on h:inputtext.
problem occurs when I do not select anything it still showing last selection,
I do not want to show anything on inputtext when "select Country" is selected

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="country_id" value="#{countryBean.countryCode}" >
                <f:validator for="country_id" validatorId="countryNameValidator"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue=" "/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.countryList}" var="countryDTO" itemLabel="#{countryDTO.countryName}(#{countryDTO.countryCode})" itemValue="#{countryDTO.countryCode}"/>
                <f:ajax event="change" render="countryCodeValue" execute="@this" listener="#{countryBean.setCountryCodeData}"></f:ajax>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText disabled="true" value="#{countryBean.countryCode}" id="countryCodeValue" required="true" >
                            </h:inputText>
```

customCountryNameValidator.java

```
package com.mcd.webex.custom.validation;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator(value="countryNameValidator")
public class CustomCountryValidator implements Validator{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void validate(FacesContext fContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value)throws ValidatorException {
    String countryCode = (String) value;
    System.out.println("from Country Validation message:"+countryCode);
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    System.out.println("Country Code length: "+countryCode.trim().length());
    if(null != countryCode && countryCode.trim().length() == 0){
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Country validation failed.","Please select country.");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }else if(null == countryCode){
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Country validation failed.","Please select country.");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code of countryNameValidator.

Comment: posted validatin file countryNameValidator

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of using `countryNameValidator`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `countryNameValidator` is the culprit. If validation fails during submitting the form, the model values won't be updated. This totally explains why you keep seeing the last **successfully** selected value. If you'd have added a `<h:messages id="messages"/>` to the form and added its `id` to the `<f:ajax render>`, then you should have seen the validation error message.

Now, I checked your validator. It actually isn't makeing any sense. It seems to be doing exactly the same as what JSF builtin `required="true"` validator already is doing. Perhaps you created it in order to prevent the blank space value of "Please select" from being submitted. This makes really no sense. Just use either `null` or an empty string as "Please select" value and stick to `required="true"`. Then you can remove that validator altogether.

This however doesn't solve the initial problem: a validation error when you change the dropdown and update the associated text element. If you have changed the validator by a `required="true"`, then this is actually simpler to solve. Let the `required` attribute evaluate `true` only if the real submit button has been pressed. Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... required="#{not empty param[submit.clientId]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.setCountryCodeData}" render="countryCodeValue" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText id="countryCodeValue" ... />
...
<h:commandButton binding="#{submit}" ... />
```

*(note that `event` and `execute` attributes of `<f:ajax>` have the right default values already; I omitted them)*